# Quickest way to create git tags in intellij without using terminal?

Tags: intellij-idea, tags

What is the quickest way to create a tag a checked-out branch without bringing up the terminal and typing `git tag -a <tagname> <commit id>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Git log window, right-click on the commit you want to tag then click `New Tag...`